# Azure DataLake client fails on creating a directory

Tags: azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I'm creating a POC to store files in Azure following the steps in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-dotnet. In the snippet below creating the directory fails with message *No such host is known. (securedfstest02.blob.core.windows.net:443)*. Appreciate any suggestion to workaround
this issue.

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake;
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataLakeHelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
            try
            {
                CreateFileClientAsync_DirectoryAsync().Wait();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        static async Task CreateFileClientAsync_DirectoryAsync()
        {
            // Make StorageSharedKeyCredential to pass to the serviceClient
            string storageAccountName = "secureblobtest02";
            string storageAccountKey = "mykeyredacted";
            string dfsUri = "https://" + storageAccountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net";

            StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);

            // Create DataLakeServiceClient using StorageSharedKeyCredentials
            DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), sharedKeyCredential);

            // Create a DataLake Filesystem
            DataLakeFileSystemClient filesystem = serviceClient.GetFileSystemClient("my-filesystem");
            if(!await filesystem.ExistsAsync())
                await filesystem.CreateAsync();

            //Create a DataLake Directory
            DataLakeDirectoryClient directory = filesystem.CreateDirectory("my-dir");
            if (!await directory.ExistsAsync())
                await directory.CreateAsync();

            // Create a DataLake File using a DataLake Directory
            DataLakeFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient("my-file");
            if(!await file.ExistsAsync())
                await file.CreateAsync();

            // Verify we created one file
            var response = filesystem.GetPathsAsync();
            IAsyncEnumerator<PathItem> enumerator = response.GetAsyncEnumerator();
            Console.WriteLine(enumerator?.Current?.Name);

            // Cleanup
            await filesystem.DeleteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this appears to be a transient error, can you share the complete code and more snips - complete error message for better understanding. How are you Authenticating ? does that have required level of access?  make sure the storage has appropriate access if through firewalls or Vnet.

Comment: I copied the whole code above. Azure storage explorer shows DFS endpoint as https://secureblobtest02.dfs.core.windows.net/. But from the exception, it looks like the client is looking for an incorrect DFS endpoint. Can't tell from where the client is picking the incorrect endpoint.

Comment: I hope you are replacing `storageAccountName ` with `secureblobtest02` in `string dfsUri` line too. And `mykeyredacted` should be replaced with on of  the access keys you find in Portal under Storage account > Security + networking setting > Access Keys

Comment: You can confirm the endpoint by navigating to Storage account > Endpoints > Data Lake Storage

Comment: Look at my comment above. I copied the DFS endpoint from Azure storage explorer. Yes, you are pointing the basic. If I had bad key, I would not have got past file system creation.

Answer (score 0):

--Update

In your question, you mention of Azure data lake, but you seem to have the host: `securedfstest02.blob.core.windows.net`

Azure Data Lake Storage uses `.dfs.core.windows.net/` whereas a Azure Blob Storage uses `.blob.core.windows.net/` While using Blob service related operations in ADLS you would have to change the endpoint too accordingly.

> please note the official MS docs [URI templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/connection-strings/storage#uri-templates).
>
> [image]

I have used the same code and was able to create directory. Just replaced my adls credentials. I have not configured any additional permissions. ADLS is Allowed access from all networks. You might want to check if yours is by default configured to `specific` network or if firewall allows client (your) IP.

[image]

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Storage;
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake;
using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace DataLakeHelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Starting....");
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Executing...");
                CreateFileClientAsync_DirectoryAsync().Wait();
                Console.WriteLine("Done");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        static async Task CreateFileClientAsync_DirectoryAsync()
        {
            // Make StorageSharedKeyCredential to pass to the serviceClient
            string storageAccountName = "kteststarageeadls";
            string storageAccountKey = "6fAe+P8LRe8LH0Ahxxxxxxxxx5ma17Slr7SjLy4oVYSgj05m+zWZuy5X8p4/Bbxxx8efzCj/X+On/Fwmxxxo7g==";
            string dfsUri = "https://" + "kteststarageeadls" + ".dfs.core.windows.net";

            StorageSharedKeyCredential sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(storageAccountName, storageAccountKey);

            // Create DataLakeServiceClient using StorageSharedKeyCredentials
            DataLakeServiceClient serviceClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), sharedKeyCredential);

            // Create a DataLake Filesystem
            DataLakeFileSystemClient filesystem = serviceClient.GetFileSystemClient("my-filesystem");
            if (!await filesystem.ExistsAsync())
                await filesystem.CreateAsync();

            //Create a DataLake Directory
            DataLakeDirectoryClient directory = filesystem.CreateDirectory("my-dir");
            if (!await directory.ExistsAsync())
                await directory.CreateAsync();

            // Create a DataLake File using a DataLake Directory
            DataLakeFileClient file = directory.GetFileClient("my-file");
            if (!await file.ExistsAsync())
                await file.CreateAsync();

            // Verify we created one file
            var response = filesystem.GetPathsAsync();
            IAsyncEnumerator<PathItem> enumerator = response.GetAsyncEnumerator();
            Console.WriteLine(enumerator?.Current?.Name);

            // Cleanup
            //await filesystem.DeleteAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I've edited storage account key, used for reference only.

Comment: Same issue persists, even if I open everything. I also tried with different DC without any luck. Are you using Azure.Storage.Files.DataLake version 12.8.0 & Azure.Storage.Common 12.9.0 or something else?

Comment: Same versions for both

Comment: I replaced new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), sharedKeyCredential) with new DataLakeServiceClient("My connection string") and everything worked. Seems to be a problem with client creation using new DataLakeServiceClient(new Uri(dfsUri), sharedKeyCredential)

Comment: like I already asked in earlier comment for question, had you replaced `storageAccountName`  with `secureblobtest02` in line `string dfsUri = "https://" + storageAccountName + ".dfs.core.windows.net";`   Cause in the code you posted, it is left as such.  It should be `string dfsUri = "https://" + "secureblobtest02" + ".dfs.core.windows.net";`

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the resulting dfsUri  is the same, if you replace the variable with a constant.

Comment: BTW, Finally I got that working also by changing ".dfs.core.windows.net" to ".blob.core.windows.net/" when initializing dfsUri.

Comment: this maybe related https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/20690